# posting to a wordpress blog using XML-RPC without credentials

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

I would like to be able to create a post from within my iPhone app/server code.
I'm guessing there is no problem doing it with XML-RPC.

The thing is that my app user needs to give me his admin user/password to the blog, which is something I would like to avoid (as a user I would have a problem disclosing this data myself)

The question is - can I avoid it somehow? Having the user install a plugin I wrote that will somehow help me seems more reasonable to me - the question is: "Will it help? What can be done?

Creative solutions are welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

Security through obscurity is never a good idea I would suggest just making your username and password the same thing while setting the user role to Author.This would all you to post with little effort.

Comment: So you are saying that the user should "manually" add a special user with Author role and should provide the credentials in the app? Can I do it for him by doing it from a plugin? (I assume my users aren't really tech savvy in wordpress - they are blog users)

Comment: You can do that, but if they're not savvy enough to do that then you might want to have them authenticate using the rpc and the wordpress mobile application for android or IOS.

Comment: Yeah, but they might not be on wordpress.com... Well - I guess I can write a plugin that generates a username/password and transmits it to my server  so I can use it later on - don't like it neither :(